# To find synonyms, definitions and example sentences using WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I need to take an input text file with a one word. I then need to find the lemma_names, definition and examples of the synset of the word using wordnet. I have gone through the book : "Python Text Processing with NLTK 2.0 Cookbook" and also "Natural Language Processing using NLTK" to help me in this direction. Though I have understood how this can be done using the terminal, I'm not able to do the same using a text editor.

For example, if the input text has the word "flabbergasted", the output needs to be in this fashion:

flabbergasted
(verb) flabbergast, boggle, bowl over - overcome with amazement ; "This boggles the mind!"
(adjective) dumbfounded , dumfounded , flabbergasted , stupefied , thunderstruck , dumbstruck , dumbstricken - as if struck dumb with astonishment and surprise; "a circle of policement stood dumbfounded by her denial of having seen the accident"; "the flabbergasted aldermen were speechless"; "was thunderstruck by the news of his promotion"

The synsets, definitions and example sentences are obtained from WordNet directly!

I have the following piece of code:

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
fp = open("inpsyn.txt")
data = fp.read()

#to tokenize input text into sentences

print '\n-----\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(data))# splits text into sentences

#to tokenize the tokenized sentences into words

tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(data)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
words = [w.lower() for w in text]  
print words     #to print the tokens

for a in words:
    print a

syns = wn.synsets(a)
print "synsets:", syns

for s in syns:
    for l in s.lemmas:
        print l.name
    print s.definition
    print s.examples
```

I get the following output:

```
flabbergasted

['flabbergasted']
flabbergasted
synsets: [Synset('flabbergast.v.01'), Synset('dumbfounded.s.01')]
flabbergast
boggle
bowl_over
overcome with amazement
['This boggles the mind!']
dumbfounded
dumfounded
flabbergasted
stupefied
thunderstruck
dumbstruck
dumbstricken
as if struck dumb with astonishment and surprise
['a circle of policement stood dumbfounded by her denial of having seen the accident', 'the flabbergasted aldermen were speechless', 'was thunderstruck by the news of his promotion']
```

Is there a way to retrieve the part of speech along with the group of lemma names?

Comment: If you log back in to SO, you should accept Andrey's answer, esp. since he not only answered, but also responded to your comments to help you out.

Answer (score 21):

```
def synset(word):
    wn.synsets(word)
```

doesn't return anything so by default you get `None`

you should write

```
def synset(word):
    return wn.synsets(word)
```

Extracting lemma names:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
syns = wordnet.synsets('car')
syns[0].lemmas[0].name
>>> 'car'
[s.lemmas[0].name for s in syns]
>>> ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'cable_car']


[l.name for s in syns for l in s.lemmas]
>>>['car', 'auto', 'automobile', 'machine', 'motorcar', 'car', 'railcar', 'railway_car', 'railroad_car', 'car', 'gondola', 'car', 'elevator_car', 'cable_car', 'car']
```

Comment: Is there a way in which I can extract only the word from the synset and pass it as a parameter? For example for the word flabbergasted, you get Synset('flabbergast.v.01') and
Synset('dumbfounded.s.01'). How can I pass these as parameters to the lemma_name function?

Comment: from nltk.corpus import wordnet

syns = wordnet.synsets('car')

[s.lemmas[0].name for s in syns]

>>>['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'cable_car']

Comment: Thanks a ton!! I have updated the code with the output. Is there a way to retrieve the part of speech separately along with the group of lemma names? For example, flabbergast, boggle and bowl over are verbs. Is there a way to get that along with the output?

Comment: to get the part of speech, use [l.synset.pos for l in s.lemmas for s in syns]

Comment: print [l.name() for s in syns for l in s.lemmas()]

Comment: how can i used my own train data?

Answer (score 5):

Here I have created a module which can easily be used(imported), and with a string being passed to it, will return all the lemma words of the string.

Module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
''' pass a string to this funciton ( eg 'car') and it will give you a list of
words which is related to cat, called lemma of CAT. '''
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import sys
#print all the synset element of an element
def lemmalist(str):
    syn_set = []
    for synset in wn.synsets(str):
        for item in synset.lemma_names:
            syn_set.append(item)
    return syn_set
```

Usage:

Note: module name is lemma.py hence "from lemma import lemmalist"

```
>>> from lemma import lemmalist
>>> lemmalist('car')
['car', 'auto', 'automobile', 'machine', 'motorcar', 'car', 'railcar', 'railway_car', 'railroad_car', 'car', 'gondola', 'car', 'elevator_car', 'cable_car', 'car']
```

Cheers!

Comment: it got error `no ImportError: No module named lemma
`

Answer (score 1):

```
synonyms = []
for syn in wordnet.synsets("car"):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())
print synonyms
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

In [`NLTK 3.0`](http://www.nltk.org/), `lemma_names` has been changed from attribute to method. So if you get an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

You can fix it using:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> [item for sysnet in wn.synsets('car') for item in sysnet.lemma_names()]
```

This will output:

```
>>> [
       'car', 'auto', 'automobile', 'machine', 'motorcar', 'car', 
       'railcar', 'railway_car', 'railroad_car', 'car', 'gondola', 
       'car', 'elevator_car', 'cable_car', 'car'
    ]
```