# Python - Return synonyms for a word in a list

Tags: python, list, api

I want to be able to use a function:

```
find_synonyms('eat')
```

and have it return:

```
['devour', 'consume', 'dine']
```

etc.

It's pretty basic, but I can't find out how.

Thank you

Comment: where do you get the dictionary?

Comment: I don't care.  Somewhere off the internet.  That's what I'm asking, where could I find like an API to do this

Comment: nltk - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258652/how-to-get-synonyms-from-nltk-wordnet-python

Comment: Is there an online version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments. The NLTK library offers a wide set of natural language processing tools.

The one you are looking for is inside the word net module of the nltk library
For excessive examples, take a look [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)

Comment: When I do something like wn.synsets('eat') it gives me a list like [Synset('eat.v.01'), Synset('eat.v.02'), Synset('feed.v.06'), Synset('eat.v.04'), Synset('consume.v.05'), Synset('corrode.v.01')].  How do I get rid of the 'Synset' stuff and leave just the words?  Sorry I'm kinda new

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535079/2526441 to be fair honest, I haven't used wordnets either. I just read about them. They tend to be very slow and performance heavy because of the huge amount of data.